# Mac Python 3.4.4, importing files/images, tkinter

Tags: python, macos, image-uploading

I am having difficulty displaying an image on a canvas using tkinter. I believe the problem arises from me improperly loading the image. Below is the code that I am trying to make work. The " file='Users/ramos1992/Desktop/test_image.gif' " is my attempt at loading an image from my desktop.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
my_image = PhotoImage(file='Users/ramos1992/Desktop/test_image.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_image)

mainloop()
```

What is the correct method of loading files using a Mac and how can I make the code work?

Comment: Is leaving the `/` off of `/Users` just a typo, or do you not understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/Users/ramos1992/Desktop/test_image.gif`, which a leading slash, is an *absolute path*: it starts at the top of your hard disk, gets the directory named `Users` there, then gets the directory named `ramos1992` there, and so on.

The path `Users/ramos1992/Desktop/test_image.gif`, without a leading slash, is a *relative path*: it starts in the current working directory. Which may be, say, `/Users/ramos1992/Documents/Python Projects`. So, you end up looking in `/Users/ramos1992/Documents/Python Projects/Users/ramos1992/Desktop/test_image.gif`, and of course there's no such location.

See [absolute and relative paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths) on Wikipedia for more details.

---

<sub>Just in case you (or someone else reading this) was a classic Mac expert back in the old days and is confused: absolute vs. relative paths have almost the exact opposite syntax between classic Mac OS-style paths and modern Mac OS X-style (Unix) paths. The old-style `Drive:Folder:Folder:File` with no prefix is `/Drive/Folder/Folder/File`, while the old-style `:Folder:File` with a prefix is `./Folder/File`, which is effectively the same as `Folder/File`, with no prefix.</sub>